# Python Regex Split interacting in a weird way

Tags: python, regex, formal-languages

I'm doing my Formal Languages assignment, and I got in some trouble trying to deal with Python Regex, using `regex.split(param)`

I've the following text:

```
{q0,q1,q2,q3},{a,b},q0,{q1,q3}
```

Which must be splitted as:

```
["q0,q1,q2,q3", "a,b", "q0", "q1,q3"]
```

It is always comma-separated, and it contains alpha-numeric values, which might start with a letter or a number.

To achieve the above separation I created this incredibly long piece of code, dealing with `String.join()` and `Array.split()`:

```
[x for x in ' '.join(' '.join(' '.join(args.split(',{')).split('}')).split('{')).split(' ') if x != '']
```

I tried the following with REGEX, but it simply doesn't work:

```
re.compile("(,{)|}|{|(},)")
```

It returns me:

```
['', None, None, 'q0,q1,q2,q3', None, None, '', ',{', None, 'a,b', None, None, ',q0', ',{', None, 'q1,q3', None, None, '']
```

It is easy to take care of all this falsey values, but why does it keeps stuff like `,{` in the array?

Comment: Do you *have* to use `split` here? It's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: What is the right tool for the job? I've never used stuff like this

Comment: It's easier to use `findall` - that way, you don't have to worry so much about the *positions* you want to split on, along with the problematic delimiters you don't want to include - instead, use `findall` to just match the subpatterns you want to *include*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the desired at once with a simple `re.findall`. Optionally repeat word characters followed by commas in a group, then finish with more word characters:

```
str = '{q0,q1,q2,q3},{a,b},q0,{q1,q3}'
re.findall(r'(?:\w+,)*\w+', str)
```

Output:

```
['q0,q1,q2,q3', 'a,b', 'q0', 'q1,q3']
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following regex:

```
import re

s = "{q0,q1,q2,q3},{a,b},q0,{q1,q3}"
m = re.findall(r"\{([A-Za-z0-9_,]+)\}|,([A-Za-z0-9_]+),", s)
if m:
    print(m)
```

Comment: What about `q0`?

Comment: Exactly like @MaorRefaeli, I've lost that ```q0``` :\

Comment: using or , it produce a tuple with empty strings , i have just to remove the empty strings , m = re.findall(r"\{([A-Za-z0-9_,]+)\}|,([A-Za-z0-9_]+),", s)

Answer (score 1):

The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/eA8mX2/7) will find anything between the outside commas and then I strip it from curly braces if they exist:

```
import re
s = '{q0,q1,q2,q3},{a,b},q0,{q1,q3}'
result = [i[1:-1] if i.startswith('{') else i for i in re.findall(r'[^,{]*(?:\{[^{}]*\})*[^,}]*', s) if i]
print(result)  # ['q0,q1,q2,q3', 'a,b', 'q0', 'q1,q3']
```

It will also work for other characters than ASCII letters:

```
import re
s = '{q0,q1,q2,q3.?!},{a,b},q0,@,{q1,q3}'
result = [i[1:-1] if i.startswith('{') else i for i in re.findall(r'[^,{]*(?:\{[^{}]*\})*[^,}]*', s) if i]
print(result)  # ['q0,q1,q2,q3.?!', 'a,b', 'q0', '@', 'q1,q3']
```

Comment: Maybe there is an option to strip the curly braces via the regex as well and also dump the empty results. If you know how you are welcome to edit my answer with more accurate result